# Silverlight Unable to Connect to Service

Tags: silverlight

I have a Silverlight Application which connects to a Silverlight enabled service. I keep getting an intermittent problem where the application freezes on a call to the web service.

This is happening at least once a day and is an intermittent problem.

The only way I can resolve this is to do an IIS reset on the server that the application is running on.

Does anyone have any ideas of why this is and how to resolve it?

I have already tried changing the recycling time of the Applicaition pool so it recycles at a certain time a day and also tried adding service throttling to the web config setting a max calls and sessions.

Comment: Do web service calls pass the rest of the time? And what type of instance management the service has? I think it would be better to use the PerCall instance management and create a new service proxy on the client side each call.

Comment: Tried changing this but it made no difference